# Typescript typecheck generate report file

Tags: typescript, next.js, report, typechecking

Hi so is there a way or 3rd party lib that can help generating report file (can be anything .html, .csv, etc.) after running typescript typechecking (in my case I'm using tsc).

So I need to generate report regarding typechecking in Next Js Project, all the output from

```
tsc --noEmit --watch --incremental
```

need to be in form of reporting file not only terminal output

Expected Flow:

1. Run TS Typecheck
2. Give an output regarding errors that happening in the form of reporting file

Notes: I'm using NextJS for my project

- Reading tsc doc
- Browse external lib

Comment: Why not just pipe the terminal output to a file?

Comment: @brc-dd I'm looking for generating proper report rather than just move the terminal output to txt file, do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

For now I just upload all the terminal output into txt file using the

```
tsc --noEmit --watch --incremental | tee -a ts-typecheck.txt
```

for the advance reporting system all I can found right now are creating our own command and create everything from scratch